# Salesforce Mobile Visualforce Quick Action Heigh Error

Tags: salesforce1-app, quickaction

In the last release (Summer' 19) we are having problems in Salesforce1 with visualforce that are used in quick actions.

The problem is that the visualforce don't have the height that we define in the quick action.

There is the quick action:

[image: Quick Action Definition]

There is how a user see the visualforce in Salesforce1:

[image: Change Status Visualforce]

Finaly we have the code of the iframe that use the quick action engine. Here I miss the heigh attribute.

[image: Quick Action Iframe Code]

Could you help me?